# Plot interdependent data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python and matplotlib

And would like to plot the following:

`x \in [0,1]`
`y \in [0, 1-x]`
`z \in [0, 1-x-y]`

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
xs = np.linspace(0,1)
```

I guess I have to loop for each `x` compute all `y` and for each `y` compute each `z`.

How can I do this and plot the results as a surface?

Comment: It’s worth browsing the Matplotlib example gallery to see if there is anything similar to what you want to do.  Click on a thumbnail and it takes you to the code that created the plot. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/index.html

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need to generate some values for `x \in [0, 1]` as you have done with `np.linspace(0, 1)`. Then, for each *fixed* x, you would need to generate a set of y values in `[0, 1 - x]` with `np.linspace(0, 1 - x)`. This gives you pairs of x and y values, essentially a square meshgrid, from which you can calculate the z values directly, and plot using `ax.plot_surface` etc. Here is a working example that uses `np.vectorize` to generate the y values from x, inspired by [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import cm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

# Generate xs in [0, 1]
xs = np.linspace(0, 1)
# For a fixed x, generate ys in [0, 1 - x]
linspaced_ys_from_x = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.linspace(0, 1 - x), signature='()->(n)')

# Each row in Y gives the lin-spaced y values in [0, 1 - x] for a fixed x,
# so each row in X should be the corresponding constant value x.
# Essentially build a meshgrid.
X = xs.repeat(xs.shape).reshape(len(xs), -1)
Y = linspaced_ys_from_x(xs)
Z = 1 - X - Y

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]